# Frictional loss of matter

Tags: friction

How do we account for the loss of matter from an object due to friction ?

Is it simply a phenomenon or result of any other process ?

Eg :The loss of matter from the rubber tyre

Comment: @bjb568 its more than enough to explain the situation i think

Comment: You mean abrasion? That produces either dust, i.e. microscopic pieces of the abraded matter or it clings to the surface on which the friction happened.

Comment: @CuriousOne Eg :The loss of matter from the rubber tyre

Comment: Rubber tires produce both dust and they leave obvious skid marks, so some of the rubber/carbon black sticks to the surface of the road.

Comment: @CuriousOne how do we account for that loss ? does it relate friction ?

Comment: Yes, it does relate to friction, but I don't know what you mean by "accounting". Are you trying to ask how much material gets abraded?

Comment: The term you are looking for is _material removal rate_ I think.